# Library/API to read dot code in Android Java and Xamarin

Tags: android, library, java, c#, barcode

I'm looking for a way to read 'dot code' barcodes from tobacco packages. Do you know any free or cheap library/API to read those codes for Android (Java or Xamarin).

I was looking for this kind of library but I couldn't find any.